# POST data are not received when a PHP script is called remotely

Tags: php, php-5.5

I don't receive $_POST data in a PHP script when it is called remotely. I tried it using cURL and Postman.

#### Content-type: form-data

`curl --location --request POST 'http://example.com/backend.php?gateway=test' --form 'status=AP'`

I would expect `status` in POST.

Response:

```
2020-09-22 13:19:27

JSON POST:

REQUEST:
Array
(
    [gateway] => test
)

GET:
Array
(
    [gateway] => test
)

POST:
Array
(
)
```

#### Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

`curl --location --request POST 'http://example.com/backend.php?gateway=test' --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' --data-urlencode 'status=AP'`

I would expect `status` in POST.

Response:

```
2020-09-22 12:59:00

JSON POST:

REQUEST:
Array
(
    [gateway] => test
)

GET:
Array
(
    [gateway] => test
)

POST:
Array
(
)
```

#### Content-Type: application/json'

`curl --location --request POST 'http://example.com/backend.php?gateway=test' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw '{ "status": "AP" }'`

I would expect `status` in JSON POST.

Response:

```
2020-09-22 13:20:43

JSON POST:

REQUEST:
Array
(
    [gateway] => test
)

GET:
Array
(
    [gateway] => test
)

POST:
Array
(
)
```

Here is the code from backend.php

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

$json = file_get_contents("php://input");

echo '<pre>';
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";
echo "\n";
echo "JSON POST:\n";
if ($json) {
    print_r(json_decode($json, true));
}
echo "\n";
echo "REQUEST:\n";
print_r($_REQUEST);
echo "\n";
echo "GET:\n";
print_r($_GET);
echo "\n";
echo "POST:\n";
print_r($_POST);
```

It works expected in localhost, but not on production. PHP version on production is 5.5.38.

Comment: Try to use `X` instead of `request`. like ` -X POST `

Comment: is a rewriterule active (perhaps to change the url from http to https or to add WWW to the domain name)? That would change the POST to a GET

Comment: @IvoP Ah yes, it is because of https. Changing to https does work. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

strange. it should work the way you're trying. can you try this:

```
curl -d "status=AP" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -X POST http://example.com/backend.php?gateway=test
```